# No se porque no se me actualiza la pantalla en kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Tengo puesta la lista como mutableList y rememberSaveable, elimino la hora que quiero pero no se me actualiza la pantalla, por lo que la hora no se elimina de la pantalla

codigo Abajo

En el viewModel solo hay un String con la fecha

---

Codigo

```
import android.util.Log
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ArrowForward
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Build
import androidx.compose.material3.Card
import androidx.compose.material3.Icon
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.material3.TextButton
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.LaunchedEffect
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember

import androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.rememberSaveable
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalContext
import com.diasApp.myapplication.ui.util.createFile
import com.diasApp.myapplication.ui.util.deleteFile

import com.diasApp.myapplication.ui.util.readFile
import com.diasApp.myapplication.viewModel.DiasViewModel

@Composable
fun DayScreen(diasViewModel: DiasViewModel){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var horasString = readFile(context, diasViewModel.fechaActual)
    var horas by rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(horasString.trim().split("\n").toMutableList())
    }

    LazyColumn() {
        items(horas) { hora ->
            cardsHora(hora, onBorrar = { horaEliminar ->
                horas.remove(horaEliminar)
            })
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun cardsHora(hora: String, onBorrar: (String) -> Unit) {
    Card {
        Row {
            TextButton(onClick = {
                onBorrar(hora)
                Log.d("HORAS", "hora : ${hora}")
            }) {
                Text(text = hora)
            }
            ComprobarDiaoNoche(hora)
        }

    }
}

@Composable
fun ComprobarDiaoNoche(hora: String) {
    val horaTemporal = hora.substring(0,2).toInt()
    if (horaTemporal > 8 && horaTemporal < 19){
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Build,
            contentDescription = "Sol"
        )
    } else {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowForward,
            contentDescription = "Luna"
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: No me acuerdo que problema había pero creo que tienes que usar un `MutableStateFlow`.

Answer (score -1):

En realidad no estas actualizando el valor, te recomiendo usar en este caso la funciona [**LaunchedEffect**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects?hl=es-419):

```
LaunchedEffect(algunValue) {
  //* Esta rutina solo se volverá a ejecutar cuando algún valor cambie.
}
```

Para esto también cambia `rememberSaveable` (el estado se retiene entre cambios de configuración) por [remember](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#remember(kotlin.Any,kotlin.Any,kotlin.Any,kotlin.Function0)) (almacena un objeto en memoria).

```
@Composable
fun DayScreen(diasViewModel: DiasViewModel){
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var horasString = readFile(context, diasViewModel.fechaActual)
    var horas by remember {
        mutableStateOf(horasString.trim().split("\n").toMutableList())
    }

    LazyColumn() {
        items(horas) { hora ->
            cardsHora(hora, onBorrar = { horaEliminar ->
                horas.remove(horaEliminar)
            })
        }
    }

    LaunchedEffect(horas) { //* observa la lista que contiene las horas.
        horasString = horas.joinToString("\n")
        //* Aquí guarda las horas!
    }
}
```